# cs50 pset7 php query function unknown column in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

not sure why this is saying 'YHOO' is an unknown column in where clause.  There is a column named symbol in my portfolio table

```
$id = 6;
$symbol = "YHOO";
$shares_query = query("SELECT shares FROM portfolio WHERE id = $id AND symbol = $symbol");
```

The query function is defined by the cs50 staff

```
function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */)
{
    // SQL statement
    $sql = func_get_arg(0);

    // parameters, if any
    $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);

    // try to connect to database
    static $handle;
    if (!isset($handle))
    {
        try
        {
            // connect to database
            $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL
            $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            // trigger (big, orange) error
            trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }
    }

    // prepare SQL statement
    $statement = $handle->prepare($sql);
    if ($statement === false)
    {
        // trigger (big, orange) error
        trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);
        exit;
    }

    // execute SQL statement
    $results = $statement->execute($parameters);

    // return result set's rows, if any
    if ($results !== false)
    {
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Doing a dump of the query parses like I would expect SELECT shares FROM portfolio WHERE id = 6 AND symbol = YHOO

Comment: "unknown column in where clause" has nothing to do with the values you're searching for. It means it can't find the COLUMN in which you are searching. Either `id` or `symbol`. So read the actual error correctly, and check your portfolio table.

Comment: You are not escaping the values, so your query reads as `SELECT shares FROM portfolio WHERE id = 6 AND symbol = YHOO`. MySQL thinks you want rows where column `id` has value 6 and column `symbol` has the same value as column `YHOO`. There is no column `YHOO`, hence the error message. Always escape your inputs! See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php on how to do this.

Comment: @TomasCreemers ok that makes sense, but I cannot find in the article you linked how to escape the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code, so that you escape your inputs, as already mention in the comments.

To get your code to work, you would need to add ' around your input, like this:

```
$id = 6;
$symbol = "'YHOO'";
$shares_query = query("SELECT shares FROM portfolio WHERE id = $id AND symbol = $symbol");
```

**EDIT:** After checking your query function, I think this is the correct way of solving it:

```
$id = 6;
$symbol = "YHOO";
$shares_query = query("SELECT shares FROM portfolio WHERE id = ? AND symbol = ?", $id, $symbol);
```

Comment: ok so this works, but now it's returning an empty array. there is a row in my table where id = 6, symbol = 'YHOO' and shares = 3.  Should this return [["shares" => 3]]?

Comment: @SeanIvins it should... print_r($shares_query); returns empty array?

Comment: @SeanIvins if you change your query, to only have the "id = ?", and not the symbol, and change your shares to *, does it still print empty array?

Comment: I actually had to use $_POST["symbol"] instead of $symbol where $symbol = strtoupper($_POST["symbol"]); no idea why this fixed it...